# how to create webservice for the java client

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've created a java client using axis jars for wsdl1. Now I've added some new methods to my client and want to create a new webservice so that end user can access wsdl1 methods and my new created methods. I've created webservice through eclipse. New WSDL(wsdl2) has generated, but server-config.wsdd doesn't contain my operations. So after deploying war file, wsdl is not accessible as a service. Means it is not accessible through http://localhost:port/Name/services/wsdlname?wsdl but it is accessible through http://localhost:port/Name/wsdl/wsdlname.wsdl. Please give suggestions how to achieve my task.

Comment: From eclipse official: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf

Comment: I've already made client. Now I want to make this client as another webservice. How can I do that.